# Access tables in a DataSet using each table's name with C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

A stored procedure returns multiple tables, the result set is assigned to a `DataSet`. Can I access the tables in the `DataSet` with each table's name?

For eg.:-

```
DataSet ds = Select(despatch_Packing_ID);
```

The `DataSet` contains 4 tables.

I am imposed to access the tables as

```
DataTable dtSales = ds.Tables[0];
```

How can I access the `DataTable` as

```
DataTable dtSales = ds.Tables["Sales"]; // Sales is tables where from I get data
```

Comment: you should be able to use the name I believe : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection.item(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection.item(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

By default the table names generated by a DbDataAdapter will have the names "Table", "Table1", "Table2", ...

You can override this by [specifying DataTableMappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks92fwwh.aspx).

For example:

```
DbDataAdapter adapter = ...
...
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Sales");
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Customers");
...
adapter.Fill(myDataSet);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a query in a stored procedure can span multiple tables and views or even simply return a single value.

How would the DataTable get its name then?

Comment: Yes. You are right. So I can not use the method that I like :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it doesn't work, because returned data may be produced from multiple joined tables. In such case there is no way to identify them by name. But I haven't checked myself, so it is just my guess.